# How do I get a special value information from a <strong>-class?

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

I am trying to extract the `data-group-id`-value from the strong written class in the given menu `vis_item`. The HTML code looks like that:

```
<div class="vis_item" align="center">
<a class="group-menu-item" data-group-id="0" data-group-type="all" href="#" data-title="">1</a>
<strong class="group-menu-item" data-group-id="1234567" data-group-type="static" data-title="">2</strong>
<a class="group-menu-item"  [.....] </a>
</div>
```

I used the following lines:

```
var group_menu = document.getElementsByClassName("vis_item"); //Get Menu-Class
var active_group_class = group_menu.innerHTML("strong"); // Get Active Menu Point
var active_group_id = active_group_class.data-group-id; // extra data-group-id Value
```

What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't look like Java to me. It's javascript with HTML. Please put correct tag

Comment: You can use this `var active_group_id = active_group_class.getAttribute("data-group-id")`. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: `group_menu[0].querySelector('strong').dataset.groupId` - see [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your js

- `getElementsByClassName` returns an array
- there's no such function as `innerHTML()`
- to get the data attribute value, you need to use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
var group_menus = document.getElementsByClassName("vis_item"); // first vis items

Array.from(group_menus).forEach(group_menu => {                // loop through vis items
  var active_group_class = group_menu.querySelector("strong"); // Get strong tag
  var active_group_id = active_group_class.dataset.groupId;    // get data-group-id Value

  console.log(active_group_id)
})
```

```html
<div class="vis_item" align="center">
  <a class="group-menu-item" data-group-id="0" data-group-type="all" href="#" data-title="">1</a>
  <strong class="group-menu-item" data-group-id="1234567" data-group-type="static" data-title="">2</strong>
  <a class="group-menu-item" [.....] </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello this is the solution i needed. It now works :-) Thank you very much.
Can you explain me, why the .dataset.groupID outputs the value from "data-group-id"? Is this, because they are the only digits in the class?

Comment: @schnalznase read the link to the dataset page I put in the answer - it tells you how data attributes are turned into dataset values for use in js

Answer (score 0):

You access data items from the element’s `dataset` attribute like the following:

```
let active_group_id = active_group_class.dataset.groupId
```

Also, `innerHTML` doesn’t work like you’re using it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Your question isn’t really clear on how you’re using the code so I wouldn’t be able to suggest an alternative but you will need to select the element using something like `this` if based on an `onclick` or `click` event or you could loop through the parent element’s children to find the `strong`.

It’s also a bit unclear why you have one `strong` amongst a load of anchor tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the code so that, if the active attribute value "data-group-id" is != my input-id, then the script shall automatically click on the link whose group-id=input-id

according to the question about the <strong>-anchor: I have no influence on the HTML file